# tools for exporting mysql db into csv files

Tags: mysql, csv

are there any solid tools  (preferably command line tools for linux) for exporting mysql db into csv files?  it needs to follow csv standards properly and handle all the newline character and other special characters properly.  select * into table does not seem to be properly converting the data correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net/).

It is Java based (therefor platform independent) and works on the [commandline](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/console-mode.html), in [batch mode](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/using-scripting.html) and as a GUI tool.

You have full control over the export format (including handling of special characters) using the [WbExport](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-export.html) command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use phpmyadmin. It has an Export feature that does that splendidly.

Answer (score 1):

There are different tools for it:

1. [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)
2. [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)
3. [Navicat for MySQL](http://www.navicat.com/)